# How to do conditional statements in pandas/python with null values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, null

How do I do condition replacements in pandas?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, None, None], [None, None, 9]])
```

In R - think this code is very easy to understand:

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% 
mutate(   #   mutate means create new column for non-r people
my_new_column = ifelse( is.na(the_2nd_column)==TRUE & is.na(the_3rd_column)==TRUE, ' abc', 'cuz')
```

how do I do this in pandas - probably dumb question with the syntax, but I have heard np.where is the equivalent of if else in R...

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(np.nan(....help here with a conditional....))
```

Answer (score 7):

`np.where` like this

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(df[1].isnull() & df[2].isnull(), 'abc', 'cuz')
print(df)
```

---

or faster with more numpy

```
df['new_column'] = \
    np.where(np.isnan(df[1].values) & np.isnan(df[2].values), 'abc', 'cuz')


     0    1    2 new_column
0  1.0  2.0  3.0        cuz
1  4.0  NaN  NaN        abc
2  NaN  NaN  9.0        cuz
```

---

***timing***

[image]

Comment: Can you please put the timings in ascending order? There is one 208us in between, it should go up. :D :P  Hehe

Comment: Thank you this works - especially the is null.....  version however I have a question if you don't mind.   If I was two append two datasets together with 1 column present in 1 dataset that is not present in the other -  the is nan version results in an error message while the is null version works.  It seems is null is more robust to errors.

Comment: Would be good to have benchmarks with a larger dataset perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.where`

```
In [279]: df['new'] = np.where(df[[1, 2]].isnull().all(axis=1), 'abc', 'cuz')

In [280]: df
Out[280]:
     0    1    2  new
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  cuz
1  4.0  NaN  NaN  abc
2  NaN  NaN  9.0  cuz
```